# Make the left text vertically center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I use bootstrap to make a page.

I have two texts, when the screen is narrow, one is above the other; when the screen is wide enough, they are displayed side by side: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/dowibesufe/edit?html,output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .frame {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="frame">
        when side by side, I want this text to be in the middle vertically.
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      Six started far placing saw respect females old. Civilly why how end viewing attempt related enquire visitor. Man particular insensible celebrated conviction stimulated principles day. Sure fail or in said west. Right my front it wound cause fully am sorry if. She jointure goodness interest debating did outweigh. Is time from them full my gone in went. Of no introduced am literature excellence mr stimulated contrasted increasing. Age sold some full like rich new. Amounted repeated as believed in confined juvenile. 
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

One format I want to realise is that when they are side by side, **the left text is vertically in the middle**. Simply adding `<br><br>` in the left text is not a good choice, because when one is above the other, I don't want `<br><br>` to remain.

I tried `vertical-align: middle`, it does not work.

Does anyone have a good way to realize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. Make your parent container a flex container, just like this:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* vertically center aligns children */
}

/* On Mobiles */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column; /* On mobile change direction */
  }
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
body {
  margin: 30px;
}

.box-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
}

/* On Mobiles */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .box-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .box {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  
  .box:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row box-container">
    <div class="box col-sm-6">
      <div class="frame">
        when side by side, I want this text to be in the middle vertically.
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="box col-sm-6">
      Six started far placing saw respect females old. Civilly why how end viewing attempt related enquire visitor. Man particular insensible celebrated conviction stimulated principles day. Sure fail or in said west. Right my front it wound cause fully am sorry if. She jointure goodness interest debating did outweigh. Is time from them full my gone in went. Of no introduced am literature excellence mr stimulated contrasted increasing. Age sold some full like rich new. Amounted repeated as believed in confined juvenile. 
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you... Are you aware of [this](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/)? I am trying to figure out that and hope to get a simpler solution...

Comment: @SoftTimur Yes, its Bootstrap v4 alpha, but its still in development. So we cannot fully rely on it until it is released, hope you got the point. Let me know if you need some other help!

Comment: @SoftTimur You are using bootstrap v3 in your snippet, that is why you are unable to use Bootstrap's Flex Grid into your JSBin. For now you can try the example I've shown in my above snippet.

Comment: I copied the links from [this page](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/) and took the example from [this page](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/) to make this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yikolikava/edit?html,output), is it normal that it does not work?

Comment: @SoftTimur Have a look at it - http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/

Comment: I did "head to the download page", I think the links in my JSBin are supposed to support Flexbox, aren't they?

Comment: @SoftTimur No you need to support flexbox manually, please check the given link carefully

Answer (score 0):

add the proper side paddings or set the proper width, or adjust the behavior of the block elements.